# Incoming TLS 1.3 sessions in Node 16/18 always generate different session ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, tls1.3

I have set up `newSession` and `resumeSession` listeners on the `httpsServer` instance, and whenever I want to compare the incoming IDs to the ones I already have stored on my backend (by literally following the official API: https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#event-resumesession), I never get a match.

My ultimate goal is to have the client re-select a certificate by "invalidating" their session(s), similar to what a simple `tlsSocket.renegotiate({})` used to do in TLS <= 1.2.

Here's the code:

```
const app = express()

app.use(cors(), json())

const httpsServer = createServer(HTTPS_OPTIONS, app)

httpsServer.on(
  'newSession',
  (
    sessionId: Buffer,
    sessionData: Buffer,
    cb: (err: Error | null, resp: Buffer | null) => void
  ) => {
    const sId = sessionId.toString('hex')

    console.log('newSession', sId)

    certificationStore.setSessionData(sId, sessionData)
    cb(null, sessionData)
  }
)

httpsServer.on(
  'resumeSession',
  (
    sessionId?: Buffer,
    cb?: (err: Error | null, sessionData?: Buffer | null) => void
  ) => {
    if (!sessionId) return

    const sId = sessionId.toString('hex')
    const existingSession = certificationStore.getBySessionId(sId)

    // always returns false
    if (existingSession) {
      certificationStore.removeSession(sId)
      cb?.(null, existingSession)
    } else {
      cb?.(null)
    }
  }
)
```

And the `HTTPS_OPTIONS` object looks like this:

```js
{
  key: fs.readFileSync(SSL_KEY_PATH),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(SSL_CERT_PATH),
  ca: [fs.readFileSync(SSL_CA_PATH)],
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
}
```

I unfortunately need to stick with TLS 1.3, and I'm appalled at how little documentation there is on what to do instead of the old `renegotiate()` method.

What is the more correct way to approach all this?